# How to add body to a SpringBoot RestTemplate Put request that has headers

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, resttemplate, unirest

## My code uses restTemplate to PUT request information and it uses the headers to do this. However, how do I add information to the body of the request?

**In UNIREST  it would be done like this:**

```
 HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.put(apiUrl + "/photos/" + photo.getId()).headers(standardHeaders()).body("{ \"status\": \"" + status + "\" }").asString();

    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
        log.error("Status " + response.getStatus() + " returned from CloudCard API when updating photo.");
        return null;
    }

    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.getBody(), new TypeReference<Photo>() {
    })
```

-

**The Code I currently have is bellow, I would like to do the same thing that I was doing with Unirest above instead with restTemplate.**

```
  public Photo updateStatus(Photo photo, String status) throws Exception {

 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

         HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
         headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
         headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
         headers.set("X-Auth-Token", accessToken);

    Photo newPhoto = photo;
    newPhoto.setStatus(status);

    ResponseEntity<Photo> response = restTemplate.exchange(apiUrl+ "/photos/" + photo.getId(),
            HttpMethod.PUT,
            new HttpEntity<Photo>(headers),
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<Photo>() {},
           newPhoto);
 return response.getBody();
 }
```

Comment: `HttpEntity` has other constructors.

Comment: Can you put a link to where the duplicate question is? I couldn't find it. also, do you have an example of how to use the other constructors because of the one with 'body' is a template so I am having a bit of trouble using it

Comment: Refresh this page. Just pass your `newPhoto` as an argument.